# How to apply pytest for Tkinter application?

Tags: python, tkinter, pytest

This is the first time I'm writing a test, and I'm doing it for a game application created with Tkinter. Its functionality: the user asks any questions and receives randomly selected basic answers from the available list. Below is a short code, then a question about the pytest module

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

RESPONSES = ['Yes', 'No']

# let's create a frame where there will be a field for user questions
frame_question_answer = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5
)
# let's create a frame that forms an area with answers to the user's questions
frame_answer = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5
)
# let's add a Text widget - a multi-line text box (as opposed to a single-line Entry)
# This area is intended for writing questions
text_box_question = tk.Text(
    master=frame_question_answer_with_scroll,
    width=67, 
    height=5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)
# widget for displaying random answers
text_box_answer = tk.Text(
    master = frame_answer_with_scroll,
    width=48, 
    height=7.5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)
# let's create an element of the Ask button
button_ask = tk.Button(
    master=frame_question_answer,
    text='Ask',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3'
)
# creating a Clear button element
button_clear = tk.Button(
    master=frame_question_answer,
    text='Clear',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3'
)
frame_question_answer.grid(
    row=0, column=0,
    columnspan=1,
    sticky='e'                       
) 
frame_answer.grid(
    row=0, column=1, 
    columnspan = 1,     
    sticky='w'                         
)
text_box_question.grid(
    row=0, column=0,                           
    sticky='news'                      
)
text_box_answer.grid(
    row=0, column=0, 
    sticky='news'                       
)
button_ask.grid(
    row=3, column=0, sticky='ew'
)
button_clear.grid(
    row=3, column=1, sticky='ew'
)
# The handler of the user's question 
def questionQuery(event):
    question = text_box_question.get('1.0', tk.END) # reading the text from the widget text_box_question
#     time.sleep(2)
    window.update_idletasks() 
    window.after(2000, lambda: button_ask.configure(text='Ask')) 
    if not question.strip():
        text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Ask your question\n') 
    else:
        answerQuery()
                    
# Random response return function
def answerQuery():
    time.sleep(2)
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Hmm...' + '\n') # and output to the text_box_answer widget
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Looking forward to learn about the future' + '\n')
    window.update_idletasks()
    window.after(2000, lambda: text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, random.choice(RESPONSES) + '\n'))

# the function of clearing the question and answer fields
def clearText(event):
    time.sleep(1)
    text_box_question.delete('1.0','end')
    time.sleep(1)
    text_box_answer.delete('1.0', tk.END)
button_ask.bind('<Button>', questionQuery)

# we bind the command to the button for clearing the question and answer fields 
button_clear.bind('<Button>', clearText)

window.mainloop()
```

Now about pytest. It is necessary to test both presented functions. To do this, I create a test module, import the and function into it...

```
from magicBallProg import questionQuery, answerQuery
import pytest

def test_questionQuery():
    questionQuery('Am I right') == 'Am I right?'

def test_answerQuery():
    pass
```

Comment: Testing gui applications is a bit tricky, I would recommend you first remove the gui code from the logic part them test only the logic, it will make the code cleaner and easier to test.